# How to remove Noise of Accelerometer with low Samplerate

Tags: python, accelerometer, lowpass-filter

i am trying to remove the Noise of my Accelerometer Data. The Problem is I have a pretty low Sample rate (only 120 Hz) but i want to recreate the movement of the Sensor as accurate as possible.

For that I tried using a lowpass-filter, Bandpass-filter and a Kalmanfilter. I had the best results using the Lowpass, but i dont know which cutoff frequency i should use. 
I know the question is a bit vague. But maybe someone has some wisdom to share with me, or any ideas what i could try to remove the noise.

```
order = 6
fs = 120.0       # sample rate, Hz
cutoff = 3  # desired cutoff frequency of the filter, Hz

dataXAcc = butter_lowpass_filter(dataXAcc,cutoff, fs, order)
dataYAcc = butter_lowpass_filter(dataYAcc,cutoff, fs, order)
dataZAcc = butter_lowpass_filter(dataZAcc,cutoff, fs, order)
plotData(dataXAcc,dataYAcc,dataZAcc,'After lowpass')
```

Here is a plot of the raw Data and after that my filtering result
(with Cutoff = 3Hz).

Raw Data:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN8rK.png)

After Lowpass: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAGnN.png)